# How can I solve the Unity GameObject Problem? Solved

Tags: unity-game-engine

When the Continue Ads gameobject is closed, the Game over button works, but when the Continue Ads is turned on, the Game over button does not work. I cannot understand why I make a mistake?

!Me fixed the problem, the problem is that I noticed that it is related to the continue ads dimension, thank you for your time.

[image]

```
void Update()
{
        if (Application.internetReachability == NetworkReachability.NotReachable)
        {
            //Debug.Log("No internet access");
            Destroy(GameObject.FindWithTag("ContinuePanel"));

        }
        else
        {
            //Debug.Log("internet connection");

            if (tag == "Skull")
            {
                ContinueAds();
            }
        }
}



public void ContinueAds()
{
    gameObject.AddComponent<AdsScript1>();
    gameoverPanel.SetActive(false);
    PausedGamePanel();
}


public void GameoverButton()
{
    gameoverPanel.SetActive(false);
    SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Can you add your expectated outcomes and the actual outcomes to your question? Without this, it's hard for us to answer

Comment: I fixed the problem thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Your continue ads object is in gameover panel. When you set  gameoverPanel.SetActive(false) you also do the same on the child objects.

Comment: I fixed the problem thank you for your help